# How to find out default jvm options when you start jar

Tags: java

How can i find out default options of a jvm when i start some jar file ? Except those options, which are specified in a command, like java -jar somefile.jar -XX:MaxPermSize=256m. So, what i need to know is there any other hided options of a jvm which i can find ?

Comment: try this? https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/

Comment: You can't specify JVM options after `-jar file` -- anything there (or after the main class name) is passed to the main class instead. `java -help` gives a summary of the 'standard' options and `java -X` the 'non-standard' single-X ones, but for version-dependent double-X options you must actually look at the documentation, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/ for j8. Note MaxPermSize is obsolete; j8 replaced permgen by metaspace years ago. @OldProgrammer: sysprops and options are different things.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do that is to search for a java process by running

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

which will show you all the JVM params.

Note: this will work only on Linux and probably MacOS

Comment: Does process have other params, except these ones ?

Comment: Most likely no, but it depends on JDK you are using and on system variables (for example if `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is set then it will append to the JVM params if you are using OpenJDK [JDK-4971166](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4971166)).